# Undefined variable in upload script

Tags: php, variables, upload, undefined

I get following errors and I don't know why.

**Notice: Undefined index: uploaded in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\upload.php on line 3**

Notice: Undefined variable: uploaded_size in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\upload.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined variable: uploaded_type in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\upload.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: uploaded in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\upload.php on line 29

I tried to include the source of the php in this post but couldn't.
Here is link to pastebin: [My source code](http://pastebin.com/YASd2GUy)

```
<?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 

 //This is our size condition 
 if ($uploaded_size > 350000) 
 { 
 echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
 $ok=0; 
 } 

 //This is our limit file type condition 
 if ($uploaded_type =="text/php") 
 { 
 echo "No PHP files<br>"; 
 $ok=0; 
 } 

 //Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
 if ($ok==0) 
 { 
 Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
 } 

 //If everything is ok we try to upload it 
 else 
 { 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 
 } 
 else 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 } 
 ?>
```

Edit 1 : I got the code from about.com [about.com](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_file_upload_5.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1.) In your $FILES array, there's no uploaded index defined. Possibly because it's `$_FILES` That's the first one. Try

```
<pre>
print_r($FILES);
print_r($_FILES);
</pre>
```

to see what is in there.

2.) ¿Where are you initializing those variables being used in the conditionals? You must extract data from the file element in the array and assign it to the variables before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The first notice is telling you that on this line:

```
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;
```

There is no 'uploaded' index into the `$_FILES` array because no file was uploaded in a form with the file input named uploaded.

The next notice is telling you that on this line:

```
if ($uploaded_size > 350000)
```

You are accessing a variable named `$uploaded_size` which has never previously been defined, so how could it possibly hold some value greater than 350000?

Same issue with the next two notices. You seem to be missing some code, and are testing code for handling uploaded files without uploading a file, or without using a form with the enctype and input names it expects.

Comment: Everything is right. I got the code from about.com. I have attached link to it in my first post. Please can you check it out.

Comment: This tutorial is poorly written and missing code. It's not right just because you copied it from someone else.

Comment: I found another tutorials. Thought it would be right because it's from such a big site about.com but apparently it wasn't. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you find that the $_FILES array does not contain any reference to your uploaded file, make sure your form tag includes enctype="multipart/form-data".